# Восприятие Python больших и маленьких букв

Tags: python

Код должен при вводе слова делать действие, но, если пользователь который откроет код и напишет слово не с большой буквы а с маленькой, то программа не воспримет это как заданное слово. Например: Москва - работает; москва - не работает. Что сделать?
Python 3.9.2

Answer (score 2):

приводишь всю строку в строчные буквы

```
s = 'Москва'
s.lower()

москва - получается
```

затем сравниваешь, например

```
if s.lower() = 'москва': print('Всё хорошо')
```

Comment: сработает даже если МоСкВа

Answer (score 1):

str.title() - пишет строку с боьшой буквы.

```
def check_wrd(s: str) -> bool:
    if s == s.title():
        return True
    else:
        return False


print(check_wrd('МоСкВа'))   # False
print(check_wrd('Москва'))   # True
print(check_wrd('москва'))   # False
```